# Solvability of the congruence $(x+a)^n\equiv x^n\pmod p$ in $x$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, perfect-powers

When thinking about [solving the diophantine $x^n-y^n=1001$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294357) I noticed that my knowledge about the prime factorisation of $x^n-y^n$ does not suffice to attack such diophantines in general. Note I'm talking about

- The Lifting The Exponent Lemma
- Zsigmondy's theorem
- Perhaps [the $\gcd\left(\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b},a-b\right)=\gcd(n\gcd(a,b)^{n-1},a-b)$ thing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146)
- ...

More specifically I got interested in the solvability of the congruence
$$(x+b)^n\equiv x^n\pmod p \tag1\label1$$
in $x$, when $b,n,p$ are fixed. (Let's assume $p$ is prime; I guess most results will generalise to composite moduli using CRT and/or Hensel's Lemma.)

> - What are some theorems regarding solutions of \eqref{1}?
> - Is it true that if \eqref{1} is solvable for $b_1$ and $b_2$, then it is solvable for $b_1b_2$?
>     *(This question is motivated by the problem I started with, because there $b$ would be a divisor of a given number.)* If not, under what non-trivial circumstances does it hold?

There exactly $\frac{p-1}{\gcd(n,p-1)}$ non-zero $n$th power residues modulo $p$, so intuitively solvability of \eqref{1} gets more likely as $\gcd(n,p-1)$ gets larger.

Comment: $\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)^n \equiv 1$

Comment: @user3491648 Ah yes; seems a very silly question now. So \eqref{1} is solvable iff $\gcd(n,p-1)>1$ (assuming $b\not\equiv0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working in $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$.

$$(x + b)^n = x^n \iff \left(1 + \frac{b}{x}\right)^n = 1 \iff u^n = 1$$
for $u = 1 + \frac{b}{x}$.

Writing $u = g^k$ for the generator $g$ produces $$kn \equiv 0 \pmod{p - 1}$$

and so on.

[edit]

We get that $p - 1 \mid kn$, so $k$ is any multiple of $\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(n, p-1)}{n}$.

This determines $u$ and then $x$.